# Gap between text and barcode with iText

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I am generate Barcode128 with library iText-2.1.3. This is code which I am using:

```
private void createBarcode(String kodDokumentu, String idSadowka, String projekt) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        File barcodePdf = new File(pathToPdf);
        Files.deleteIfExists(barcodePdf.toPath());
        Document document = new Document();
        Rectangle size = new Rectangle(151,60);
        document.setMargins(5, 1, -6, 0);
        document.setPageSize(size);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathToPdf);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);

        document.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        Barcode barcode128 = new Barcode128();
        barcode128.setBarHeight(40);
        barcode128.setX(1.04f);
        barcode128.setCode("VL#"+kodDokumentu.toUpperCase());
        barcode128.setCodeType(Barcode.CODE128);
        Image code128Image = barcode128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
        Font code = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("ID: "+idSadowka+",   Projekt: "+projekt.substring(0, 2), code);
        document.add(p);
        document.add(code128Image);
        document.close();
        fos.close();
    }
```

I want to achive as small `h` (take a look at image) as it is possible, best if `h=0.01` because I want to save more place for `ID: xxxxx, Projekt: xx` to make it bigger and easier to read by human.
First (bottom barcode) I used font size 8, then (upper barcode) I tried to change font size to 10 but when I did it `h` is bigger than previous. I know that font size is connected with gap between barcode and text above it but is it possible to use bigger font size and set this gap really small?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's available in the version of iText you use, but on iText 5 at least, you have the option to set the "spacing after" on Paragraphs. It would be exactly what you need, i.e. you specify a fixed space under the paragraph, and any elements you add to the document after that paragraph, will go under that space.

```
p.setSpacingAfter(x)
```

Where x being the space you need, in user units or "points".

Comment: Well in documentation:
`public void setSpacingAfter(float spacing)

Description copied from interface: Spaceable
Sets the spacing after.

Specified by:
    setSpacingAfter in interface Spaceable
Parameters:
    spacing - the new spacing `

it seems that it is adding new space after `Paragraph` and it's not what I am looking for - I would like to make it smaller, not bigger.

Comment: Did you try to set it to 0, or negative value?

Comment: Should have figure it out by myself. `p.setSpacingAfter(-5.0f);` did the job, thanks a lot!